# Lifting Solutions to Congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was working through a paper on efficient congruencing when I came across the following, but I can't understand why it is correct. For reference $\xi$ is an integer and $1 \leq \xi \leq p$ where $p$ is a prime. My instinct is that it is Hensel's Lemma related, but I haven't been able to find any resources to help me with that.

Assuming $\textbf{x}$ to be well-conditioned, that is, $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are in distinct congruence classes modulo $p$ then for a fixed $\textbf{n} \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ we can lift solutions to 
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i = 1}^k (x_i - \xi)^j \equiv n_j \quad (mod\  p) \quad (1 \leq j \leq k)
\end{equation*}
With $1 \leq \textbf{x} \leq p$ uniquely to solutions to
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i = 1}^k (x_i - \xi)^j \equiv n_j \quad (mod\  p^k) \quad (1 \leq j \leq k)
\end{equation*}
With $1 \leq \textbf{x} \leq p^k$.

Comment: You need a bound on $k$ that is the summation limit, and you should rename the exponent of $p$.

Comment: Those are the same fixed $k$, there is no given bound for $k$.